# Editing a WordPress Theme to resemble another site based off same theme

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

Building a Word Press based site using the Suburbia Word Press theme.

Trying to get the main page to resemble this site (http://appazoogle.com/) which uses the same theme.  I need for the arraignment of the postings to resemble the ones on the main page of appazoogle.  What's the secret?

My site is:
http://galleryeastnetwork.com/wordpress/

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about the first 3 posts being way wider than the rest of the site, then it seems like you just need to change out the HTML classes of the first three posts to be `post one` instead of `post two`

Provide more information on what you are trying to do and I would be glad to help

This would take place in the section you have commented, `FIRST LOOP`

Comment: And by that, I mean how the posts are set up like table columns.

Comment: Looks like @david.binda changed the classes for you.

Comment: not only classes - also formula for computing offset in a right way ;)

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say what specific difference you want to remove. If it is those two big posts on the top, than you have to modify home.php of Suburbia theme from this

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

    <?php include (TEMPLATEPATH . "/sidebar.php"); ?>        
    <?php
        if ( $paged == 0 ) {
            $offset1 = 0;
            $offset2 = 2;
        } else {
            $off = $paged - 1;
            $offset1 = $off * 7;
            $offset2 = $off * 7 + 2;
        }
    ?>
    <!-- LOOP1 -->
    <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
    <?php query_posts('posts_per_page=2&offset='.$offset1); ?>
    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <div class="post two">
```

To this:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

    <?php include (TEMPLATEPATH . "/sidebar.php"); ?>        
    <?php
        if ( $paged == 0 ) {
            $offset1 = 0;
            $offset2 = 4;
        } else {
            $off = $paged - 1;
            $offset1 = $off * 7;
            $offset2 = $off * 7 + 4;
        }
    ?>
    <!-- LOOP1 -->
    <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
    <?php query_posts('posts_per_page=4&offset='.$offset1); ?>
    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <div class="post one">
```

It is not only about class. It is also about correct offset.

Comment: You're welcome. Try to mark my answer as the right one, please ;)

Comment: They are set to have dynamic height according to their content. No need to modify their height, thou. But if you insist on higher bottom boxes, you can modify your stylec.css and add .bottom{ min-height: 500px; } to it's end...

Comment: I actually meant the last boxes at the bottom.  The row that has the search widget.